# Best and safe way to move a big folder

Tags: linux

I want to move folder "X" from /var/www/site1 to /var/www/site2...

Is "mv" the best option? (Linux)

Comment: Is it the same file system? If so size is not important for `mv`

Comment: @vidarlo .. yep that is same filesystem. just a different "directory"

Comment: Your post seems to have gotten an acceptable answer, but you did not mark it as solved. Please specify what additional details you are looking for, or mark it as solved by clicking the outline of the tick mark so that it turns solid green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is the same file system, `mv` will do the move just fine in a short amount of time, as no data is actually moved; only references are updated.